# Get instance of main window controller in app delegate

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I know that, for iOS, you can reference the root view controller from the app delegate like so:

var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController

How does one reference the main window controller from the app delegate when targeting OS X? I would like to pass a variable (the managed object context) this way, as I have read that it is a good solution for referencing the moc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can access the NSWindowController instance of the main NSWindow like this:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow?.windowController
```

Comment: Swift 3 NSApplication.shared().mainWindow!

Comment: **Swift 4:** `NSApplication.shared.mainWindow!` :)

Comment: I'd suggest not force unwrapping that as it may be nil if the user has closed all windows but not the application itself.

Comment: It's nil in applicationDidFinishLaunching

Answer (score 0):

The ! in earlier answers will cause a crash if the window is hidden, so I recommend caching the window either like this or using a computed property:

```
var mWindow: NSWindow? = nil
func mainWindowCached() -> NSWindow? {
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow {
        self.mWindow = window
    }
    return self.mWindow
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access like this:

```
NSApplication.shared().mainWindow?.contentViewController as! YourViewController;
```